# Phoenix csv Bulk load fails with large data sets

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, azure-hdinsight, apache-phoenix

I'm trying to load a dataset (280GB) using the Phoenix csv bulk load tool on a HDInsight Hbase cluster. The job fails with the following error:

> 18/02/23 06:09:10 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id :
>   attempt_1519326441231_0004_m_000067_0, Status : FAILEDError: Java heap
>   spaceContainer killed by the ApplicationMaster.Container killed on
>   request. Exit code is 143Container exited with a non-zero exit code
>   143

Here's my cluster configuration:

```
Region Nodes
8 cores, 56 GB RAM, 1.5TB HDD
Master Nodes
4 cores, 28GB, 1.5TB HDD
```

I tried increasing the value of yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb from 5GB to 38GB, but the job still fails.

Can anyone please help me troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details ? Such as how are you kicking off the job? Are you following the instructions here - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredatalake/2017/02/14/hdinsight-how-to-perform-bulk-load-with-phoenix/ ?

Specifically Can you provide the command you used and also some more info as in is the job failing immediately or does it run for a while and then start to fail? Any other log messages than the one you described above ?